# BoxLayout left margin for TextField

Tags: java, swing, margin, textfield, boxlayout

I am using a BoxLayout and I have 2 JTextFields. I need to add some margin options to them because they are too close to the window border.

[image: http://i62.tinypic.com/mk875t.png]

Code:

```
JPanel top = new JPanel();
top.setLayout(new BoxLayout(top, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));
top.add(new JLabel("Recipient:"));        
recipient.setMaximumSize( recipient.getPreferredSize() );
top.add(recipient);
top.add(new JLabel("Subject:"));
subject.setMaximumSize( subject.getPreferredSize() );
top.add(subject);
top.add(new JLabel("Message:"));
add("North", top);
```

If I add a HorizontalStrut, it affects only the Labels, and TextFields not. Thank you in advice!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `Border` to the panel:

```
JPanel top = new JPanel();
top.setBorder( BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(....) );
```

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to use Borders](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/border.html) for more information and examples.